# Using Slick with Kudu/Impala

Tags: scala, jdbc, slick, impala, apache-kudu

Kudu tables can be accessed via Impala thus its jdbc driver. Thanks to that it is accessable via standard java/scala jdbc api. I was wondering if it is possible to use slick for it. Or if not is any other high level scala db framework supporting impla/kudu.

Answer (score 0):

Slick can be used with any JDBC database

http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.3.0/database.html

Answer (score 0):

At least, for me, Slick is not fully compatible with Impala Kudu. Using Slick, I can not modify db entities, can not create, update or delete any item. It works only to **read data**.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could use Slick with an arbitrary JDBC driver (and SQL dialect).

The first is to use low-level JDBC calls. The `SimpleDBIO` class gives you access to a JDBC connection:

```
val getAutoCommit = SimpleDBIO[Boolean](_.connection.getAutoCommit)
```

That example is from the [Slick manual](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.0/dbio.html#jdbc-interoperability).

However, I think you're more interested in working at a higher level than that. In that case, for Slick, you'd need to implement a custom [Profile](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/JdbcProfile.scala). If Impala is similar enough to an existing database profile, you may be able to `extend` an existing profile and adjust it to account for any differences. For example, this would allow you to customize how SQL is formatted for Impala, how timestamps are represented, how column names are quoted. The documentation on [Porting SQL from Other Database Systems to Impala](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_porting.html) would give you an idea of what needs to change in a driver.

> Or if not is any other high level scala db framework supporting impla/kudu.

None of the main-stream libraries seem to support Impala as a feature. Having said that, the [Doobie documentation](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/14-Managing-Connections.html#customizing-transactors) mentions customising connections for Hive. So Doobie may be worth quickly trying Doobie to see if you can query and insert, for example.